# How to make a timer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently having difficulties creating a timer. The timer sort of works, but I'm having issues converting the milliseconds into minutes/hours/seconds.

If someone could please help me and edit/guide me through what i currently have that would be amazing!

The variable `inter` is set to a random number. I need some code that analyzes how big the number is and decides whether to display it as milliseconds, minutes, or hours.

```
// JS wait function 

setTimeout(() => {
    function toBeRepeated(){
      var inter = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000000) + 500000; 
      testchannel.send("hi"); 
      var inter1 = (inter % 60000 / 1000).toFixed(2);
        setTimeout(toBeRepeated, inter);
            console.log("Message sent to server 1");
            console.log("Next message will be sent in " + inter1 + " seconds");

    }
    toBeRepeated();
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 2000);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to convert inter into seconds?

Comment: "sort of works" and "having issues" are not clear descriptions of either the problem you're experiencing, or the desired goal of the software. Please describe the requirements precisely and clearly, including examples of input and desired behaviour and output, so we know enough detail to be able to program it precisely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vague answer:

```js
var inter = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000000) + 500000; 

var hours = Math.floor(inter / 1000 / 60 / 60);
var minutes = Math.floor(inter / 1000 / 60) - hours * 60;
var seconds = Math.floor(inter / 1000) - minutes * 60 - hours * 60 * 60;
var ms = inter - seconds * 1000 - minutes * 60 * 1000 - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;

console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the input is in miliseconds, you can use something like this so transform it to this format hh:mm:ss:ms. No .floor() needed

```
function formatTime(time) {
  var ms = time % 1000;
  time = (time - ms) / 1000;
  var secs = time % 60;
  time = (time - secs) / 60;
  var mins = time % 60;
  var hrs = (time - mins) / 60;

  return hrs + ':' + mins + ':' + secs + ':' + ms;
}

console.log(formatTime(50000000)) // "13:53:20:0"
```